# Potential Bug In Google Chrome Scroll Snapping

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a simple scroll snapping code below which works perfectly in Firefox 80.0.1 where as in Google Chrome v85.0.4183.102 he scrolling behavior isn't smooth and there is a delay in the snapping effect. Here is a link to a screen recording in [Firefox](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiMsz2-M9qKqjJSuy7SKTWzVybNdaFX8/view?usp=sharing) and [Google Chrome](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkXFn-Z6yQZEtzPcRFlu50txrKFDON7-/view?usp=sharing). From what I know scroll snapping should be supported in the major browsers as from [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=Scroll%20Snap).

Here are  my code snippets

```
<body>
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque ut veritatis accusantium exercitationem, accusamus dolores eveniet. Adipisci hic soluta reiciendis nihil accusantium quam facilis. Animi earum culpa voluptate magni.</section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque ut veritatis accusantium exercitationem, accusamus dolores eveniet. Adipisci hic soluta reiciendis nihil accusantium quam facilis. Animi earum culpa voluptate magni.</section>
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cumque ut veritatis accusantium exercitationem, accusamus dolores eveniet. Adipisci hic soluta reiciendis nihil accusantium quam facilis. Animi earum culpa voluptate magni.</section>
</body>

html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Here is a workable demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/cb5nraxq/

Is this a known bug on Google Chrome or did I set something wrong? I'm on Windows BTW

**EDIT**
The issue only occurs when scrolling use mousewheel

Comment: the snapping works when clicking the scrollbar on the side of the page and use that to scroll down/up, but with the mousewheel it messes up for me in chrome

Comment: Yup that is the issue I'm pointing out. Let me edit my post

Comment: To confirm; The snapping works fine for me on Firefox but screws up on Chrome  85.0.4183.102 using mouse wheel scrolling.

Comment: `scroll-snap-type` is not supported on either browser, yet.

Comment: If it isn't supported on either browser why does it work well on Firefox 

Comment: @DexterSiah I guess it's not *formally* supported, but it currently works in Firefox but that's not to be relied upon going forwards.....

Comment: @DexterSiah submit a bug report to [Google Chrome Bug Report Team](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en),

Comment: Yeah seems like that is the case. Will do send a bug report.